# Attaching decorator to class causes error in Typescript:TS2539: Cannot assign to 'AppModule' because it is not a variable

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, webpack-4, tsconfig

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule
]
})

export class AppModule {

    constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) {
    }

    ngDoBootstrap() {
         this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['ng1migrate'], {strictDi: true});
    }
}
```

I am trying to upgrade to Angular from AngularJs(1.6.6) and  dual booting. When I build the project using webpack4 it gives the error

tsconfig.json  for reference

{

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "",
  "declaration": false,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "lib": ["es6", "dom","ES2015"],
  "mapRoot": "./",
  "module": "es6",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "target": "es5",
  "typeRoots": [
    "../node_modules/@types"
  ]
}
```

}

webpack.config.js for refernce

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app/main.ts',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    resolve:{
        extensions:[".webpack.js",".web.js",".ts",".tsx",".js"]
    },

    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'ng-annotate-loader?ngAnnotate=ng-annotate-patched!ts-loader',
            },
            {test:/\.tsx?$/, use:"ts-loader"},

        ]
    },
}
```

versions:
  "ts-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"

Comment: post your tsconfig

Comment: {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "",
      "declaration": false,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "lib": ["es6", "dom","ES2015"],
      "mapRoot": "./",
      "module": "es6",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "target": "es5",
      "typeRoots": [
        "../node_modules/@types"
      ]
    }
  }

Comment: not sure this is the issue but I think angular needs `"downlevelIteration": true,` as well... otherwise the issue is elsewhere as this looks good

Comment: adding it didn't help

Comment: then the issue is somewhere else as this is all fine. are you actually attempting to assign to your module when you do the app bootstrap in main?

Comment: no in main.ts I did platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

Comment: ah wait... this seems problemativ `"module": "es6",` ... can you use esnext or commonjs? es6 modules work differently

Comment: didn't help updating to esnext or commonjs

Comment: stumped then. would need to see more of the code. migrations are always tricky to get running at first.